# Why doesn't my external css-file work?

Tags: html, css

Here´s my css code:

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://relevantfl.org/wp- content/uploads/2013/07/light_grey_3000x3000.jpg);  
    color: white;
    font: 12px/1.4em Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Here´s my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
<link href=”/Users/EdvinHedblom/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/design.css” rel=”stylesheet” type="text/css"  media="all" />
</head>
```

The problem is that when i run the code in browser it only shows my html-code and no style at all.

Comment: This means that you are not refering to the `CSS` path correctly

Comment: There is no any image on link which you given. And you given color white and font. But there is no any text in your HTML. so. didn't show anything. Also make sure you given correct css path.

Comment: Be sure to use the right quotes (e.g. `'` and not `) when writing, since this will seriously screw up code!

Answer (score 2):

You have used bad quotes, use `"` or `'`.

```
<link href="/Users/EdvinHedblom/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
```

Then remember then you are linking file from your local machine, remote server can find it if you move your HTML to server.